# Should I mention previous visa withdrawals in UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I had applied for UK Tier 2 visa and realised one of the documents I had submitted was incorrect along with multiple other errors. So I withdrew my application so that it wouldn't get rejected.

I am planning to apply again with correct documents and details this time around. Should I mention in the second application that I had previously withdrawn an application? It does not specifically ask for this, I would put it in the 'State anything else you would like us to know' section.

---

I applied again and it was rejected as I forgot to attach a document, the refusal letter only mentioned the missing document as the reason, so I assume that the withdrawn application was not a factor in this?

Comment: Does the application ask for this?

Comment: No, it does not ask for it. However they do have a text input box at the end stating `state anything else which you would like us to know`. Will they treat my application as fraudulent if I don't mention it here?

Comment: @GriffinTaimer The visa officer can refuse your application for the first serious reason they spot, they may, but don't have to, list other reasons as well. Hence, that your application was rejected for the missing document, does not allow for a conclusion with regard to the withdrawn application.

Answer (score 1):

It will not hurt to add (in that last area) that you had applied and withdrawn because you noticed you had made mistakes in the application.

If they want to know or had seen you had applied before, you will be covered by entering the fact.

While getting the reaction where they only mention one missing document may indicate that they do not worry about earlier withdrawn applications, it can also mean that the officer just did not bother to mentioned it and that they do want you to mention it.